# ASP.NET Trigger UpdatePanel on HTML Button click

Tags: asp.net

I have created a User Control in which I use a JQuery Plugin (DataTables).
I would like to refresh the User Control when I click on a button that I have generated inside the User Control like this :

```
_DT += "<button id=\"validConf\" runat=\"server\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" onclick=\"$('#modalConfig_" + ID + "').modal('hide');\">Valid</button>"
```

Now, in my Page I have the following code :

```
    <asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <UC:Grille runat="server" ID="Grille1"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="validConf" /> 
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It returns this error : "Unable to find control in Update Panel for trigger"

Am I not doing it the good way or am I missing something ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: Are you generating servercontrols with string concanetation? That's not possible. You have to add controls to the `Page`'s control-collection

Comment: Yes. Shoud l i create the servercontrols in the ascx file of my UserControl instead ?